# Pythonic way of finding elements of list not returned by SQL query

Tags: python

I have a list of objects `Foo` which have a uniquely identifying key, `foo_key`. I query a MySQL database for all rows in the table `FooData` which are in my list of `Foo` objects:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM FooData where foo_key in ({})".format(",".join(str(obj.foo_key) for obj in foo_list))
foo_rows = sql_exec(sql).fetchall()
```

What would be the most pythonic way of finding out which of my `Foo` objects are not in the database (i.e. do not have a corresponding row in the returned `foo_rows`?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SQL so replace these with the equivalent

```
keys_not_in_db = set(list_of_foo_list_keys) - set(list_of_foo_rows_keys)
```